# htaccess mod_rewrite - exclude last / in REQUEST_URI

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried searching for the answer to this but I can't seem to find an answer.

What I want is when somebody goes to a page, apache checks if a cache file exists for that page and then loads that instead of letting php serve it.

EG: http://example.com/about
For this, I use the code below and it works. But as soon as I add a / on the end like this: http://example.com/about/ It doesn't work anymore. I tried making my cache file include the slash but that's not possible.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(POST)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cached_pages/%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule . %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cached_pages/%{REQUEST_URI}.html
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You're capturing everything, so the rewrite URL ends up like this: `cached_pages/about/.html`. Try something like `RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cached_pages/$1.html`

Comment: @ishegg that seems to work well for the rule, thanks! But cant I do that for the condition above it? I actually found a solution. I will put it as my answer and if someone else has a better one they can post it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. @ishegg helped me with the RewriteRule and for the ReWriteCond I used a variable.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^(.+?)/?$" PATH=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(POST)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cached_pages/%{ENV:PATH}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cached_pages/$1.html
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That's really clever using the ENV variable. Cheers!